# Creating a Search Tab Bar, from a Segue and Passing through the ManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, search, core-data, tableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I had a working app with a single `UITableViewController`; when you press the Add button, it brings up a `ModalViewController` and the user can add text into the text field, press save and through `NSFetchedResultsController`, that would successfully update the `UITableView` cells.

I also had a search button on the TableView which would call up, modally a Search Controller with a search tab; I could type in, press Search and it would find records in that table. It had a cancel button to go back.

I want to modify the UI so the search is part of a tab bar on the bottom of the TableView and remove the button.

My TableView had a `prepareForSegue` method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Search"])
    {
        SearchViewController *searchEntry = (SearchViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
        searchEntry.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext; 
        //[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:searchEntry animated:YES];
    }
}
```

So I was basically passing the `managedObjectContext` across.

Now because I'm using the Tab, I suspect there's no `prepareForSegue` equivalent? So my question is, how would the `managedObjectContext` across?

My `SearchViewController` looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.tView.delegate = self;
    self.tView.dataSource = self;

    noResultsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 90, 200, 30)];
    [self.view addSubview:noResultsLabel];
    noResultsLabel.text = @"No Results";
    [noResultsLabel setHidden:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}

// Once the user taps "search" on the keyboard, you run a fetch and show the results on the table view, or display the No Results label.
// This is one of the SearchBar Delegate methods
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    NSError *error;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error in search %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    } else
    {
        [self.tView reloadData];
        [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
        [noResultsLabel setHidden:_fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count > 0];
    }
}

- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id sectionInfo= [[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Transaction *info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [info valueForKeyPath:@"whoBy.name"]]];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [info valueForKeyPath:@"occasion.title"]]];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Transaction" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"whoBy.name" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY whoBy.name CONTAINS[c] %@", self.searchBar.text];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

When I run this, nothing searches at all. If I put the following code at the top of the class, I get the error below it:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}
```

:

```
<NSInvalidArgumentException> +entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Transaction'
```

So I'm basically creating the same functionality, but I want to "pass" the managedObjectContext from the TableView tab bar over to the `SearchBarViewController` tab and do the searching, the way it was working before.

Other relevant information; I have a property for the `NSManagedObjectContext` and `NSFetchedResultsController` in this search file.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Why won't you use a search bar? also, your `if` in the `managedObjectContext` method is redundant. simply call `return [delegate managedObjectContext];`

Comment: Dear Dan, thanks for your reply - I actually got it working by using the NSManagedObjectContext which worked in the end..